# Conflict between jQuery Tools and another jQuery script

Tags: html, conflict, jquery

I'm using [jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/)(specifically, the form validator) and a [JQuery Facebook-related script](http://archives-mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/index.html) on one page of my website.

Each script requires referencing both an external file in the "head" of my HTML as well as a separate script in the "body" of my HTML.

Here is my code for the scripts in the "body" of my HTML (simplified):

**First Script (Facebook script)**
`

```
                function init() {
                  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    $(".s_name").replaceWith('<input type="hidden" name="s_name" id="' + response.name + '" value="' + response.name + '" />');
                    ..do more replaceWith stuff
                  });
                }
                //Live update of page as user selects recipient and gift options
                $(".jfmfs-friend").live("click", function() {
                  var friendSelector = $("#jfmfs-container").data('jfmfs');             
                  ...do stuff});  
              `
```

**Second script (jQuery Tools - validator)**
`

```
            $("#form").validator({
              position: 'top left',
              offset: [-5, 0],
              message: '<div><em/></div>',
              singleError: true
            });
          `
```

Everything works correctly until the .click function of the first script is activated. At that point, the validator script stops working. I believe the issue is related to conflicting jQuery $'s, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried using `jQuery.noConflict()` in various areas, but I haven't been successful and I'm not exactly sure how I should be using it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Fix it by including jquery tools first, and not including jquery.js. jQuery tools for some reason includes jquery directly within it (or atleast it used to)

Comment: @KevinB, it's optional, and nowadays comes without it by default! See [jQuery Tools Download](http://jquerytools.org/download/)

Comment: That's actually how it's setup now, and it's not working. 
My header:
`<!--jQuery Tools-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"</script>

<script src="js/jquery.facebook.multifriend.js"></script>`

Do you think I need to use jQuery.noConflict() somewhere? I thought that was the issue, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: You don't need noConflict() if you aren't including jQuery twice.

Comment: @Zuul The fact that it used to include the core is why I never used it. I didn't want to find out what other horrid decisions they were making for me behind the scenes. Nice to know they are moving away from that.

Comment: Oh ok. Weird, I have no idea what the issue is then.

Comment: @Stone, you get no errors at all?

Comment: @KevinB, yap, personally I don't use jQuery tools for over an year now, make it two.. very useful, but heavy and full of quirks! (_personal opinion_).

Comment: Nope. I have a form on my website that uses jQuery tools for validation. Also on the page is a place for the user to select a friend from Facebook using the jQuery FB script. Once the user has logged into the Facebook app, they are shown a list of friends which they can "select" (not select in the sense of an HTML form, just a CSS color change using .replaceWith). At this point the  jQuery tools validator works for the other form fields. But if the user "selects" a FB friend, and then clicks the submit button, nothing happens (jQuery tools doesn't validate, and the form doesn't submit).

Comment: And just to clarify, if the user does NOT select a FB friend (but DOES login), clicking the submit button successfully runs the validation and submits the form.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to this line of code which is in the .live click function of the FB app:

`$(".first_name").replaceWith('<input type="text" name="r_first" value="first name" class="first_name" placeholder="first name" data-message="Enter a first name" required>');`

All it does is replace a previously empty form input with the same input but with a value now set. If I comment this line out, everything works fine. Other calls to replaceWith work just fine. This is the only input, which is also the only input validated by jQuery Tools, that I can not successfully call .replaceWith on.

Comment: Use **Firebug** or **Developer Tools** from Chrome to debug and test. You will usually see JS errors and notices in the console when something is wrong.

Comment: I tried that, but no errors are shown :/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `'jQuery'` in place of all `'$'` like so:

`jQuery(document).ready(function() {});` as against `$(document).ready`...

I was forced to use the long version during a "conflict" of interest situations.